# Assets wont get rendered after disposing and reloading them

Tags: java, libgdx, assets

In my game I have currently two screens. The `MenuScreen` and the `GameScreen`. Through the Play option in the menu the player can switch to the GameScreen and start the Gameplay and with Escape he can get back to the MenuScreen. I dispose the used Assets when I switch to the other Screen in the `hide()` method and load the needed Assets for the new Screen in the constructor of the Screen I switch to. The problem is that the Textures and Sound Effects aren't rendered/played when I switch back. 
For example when I start the game in the `MenuScreen`, then switch to the `GameScreen` everything is fine. But when I switch back to the `MenuScreen` the `MenuScreen` is just a black window. When I then switch to the `GameScreen` again it's black too except for the BitmapFont.
Maybe there is a fundemental flaw in the way I handle this. I tried to leave out as much unnecessary things as I can from the code I post here, but I fear that it's still too much.

RessourceLoader Class:

```
public class RessourceLoader {

    public static AssetManager manager;


    public static void create() {
        manager = new AssetManager();
    }

    public static void loadMenuScreen() {
        manager.load("gfx/menuBackground.png", Texture.class);
    }

    public static void getMenuScreen() {
        menuBackground = manager.get("gfx/menuBackground.png", Texture.class);
    }

    public static void disposeMenuScreen() {
        menuBackground.dispose();
    }

    public static void loadGameScreen() {
        // load GameScreen Assets through AssetManager
    }

    public static void getGameScreen() {
        // get GameScreen Assets through AssetManager
    }

    public static void disposeGameScreen() {
        // dispose all GameScreen Assets
    }

    public static void dispose() {
        manager.dispose();
    }
}
```

MenuScreen Class:

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

    // Game starts in the MenuScreen

    // Instance of game
    private PHGame game;
    // Orthographic camera
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    public MenuScreen(PHGame phGame) {
        game = phGame;      
        RessourceLoader.loadMenuScreen();
        RessourceLoader.manager.finishLoading();
        RessourceLoader.getMenuScreen();

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, 640, 480);

        game.batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        // Fills background with black to avoid flickering
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Begin Drawing
        game.batcher.begin();      

        // Draw Menu

        // Stop drawing
        game.batcher.end();

        // Pressing Space confirms currently selected menu item
        if (GameKeys.isPressed(GameKeys.SPACE)) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }

        // Update Key Presses
        GameKeys.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        RessourceLoader.disposeMenuScreen();
    }
}
```

GameScreen Class:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    // Instance of game
    private PHGame game;

    private GameWorld world;
    private GameRenderer renderer;
    private float runTime;


    public GameScreen(PHGame phGame) {
        game = phGame;
        RessourceLoader.loadGameScreen();
        RessourceLoader.manager.finishLoading();
        RessourceLoader.getGameScreen();
        world = new GameWorld(game, this);
        renderer = new GameRenderer(world, game);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // runTime is the amount of time the game is running
        runTime += delta;
        // Updates the Game World
        world.update(delta);
        // Renders everything
        renderer.render(runTime);
        // Update Key Presses
        GameKeys.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        RessourceLoader.disposeGameScreen();
    }
}
```

GameRenderer Class:

```
public class GameRenderer {

    // Instance of PHGame
    PHGame game;
    // Instance of Game World
    private GameWorld world;
    // Orthographic Camera
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    // If true hitbox's will be shown
    private boolean showHitbox;

    // Game Objects
    private Player player;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world, PHGame game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.world = world;
        player = world.getPlayer();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, 640, 480);
        showHitbox = false;

        game.batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    }

    public void render(float runTime) {
        // draw objects and hud      
    }
}
```

If there are any questions regarding my problem I'll try to answer then as good as I can.

Comment: I would say that your assumption about the amount of code being too much is correct.

Comment: Do not dispose of assets that were loaded with an AssetManager. Call manager.unload on them instead. But you do need to dispose of the asset manager when you're totally done with it.

Comment: Thanks. Changed it to unload and it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the github article 'managing your assets'. AssetManagers should not be static. 'This typically would cause black/missing textures or incorrect assets.'

After you dispose your asset manager it can no londer be used. Instead use manager.unload to unload assets. `manager.unload("gfx/menuBackground.png");`

EDIT:

I also didn't see any overriden show() methods. If you want your assets back you will need to load your assets in the screen's show method every time.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I will look into the gitHub article. :)
I didn't include the show() method because it was empty and I didn't want to waste any space. Is there a difference between loading them in the show() method and loading them in the constructor?

Comment: absolutely, in the constructor it will only load once the object is instantiated. In show() it will be loaded every time you switch to the screen

Comment: Oh I see that you make a new screen each time you switch, so I guess in your case it wouldn't matter

Comment: Yeah that's why I was wondering. Still good to know for the future! I used unload() instead of dispose() and it works now. Thanks allot for your help. I will now look into the gitHub article and also change it to load the assets in the show() method :)

Comment: Loading in the show() method will allow you to keep all of screens in memory instead of having to create a new screen every time. You could then `game.setScreen(game.mainMenuScreen);` for example.

Comment: Yes I changed it now so it doesn't create a new Screen every time, but instead keeps it in the memory. Thanks again for your help. Without SO I would be lost :P